# Image Pasting in Internet Explorer (and the Web Browser Control)

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, clipboard

I'm trying tot handle Image Pasting into HTML content using the HTML DOM and the `paste` event. I can get the paste operation to work in Chrome and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer I can't get the event to fire at all, either in web mode or running off a local file in the Web Browser control (in IE11 mode).

Text pasting works, but when I have an image loaded in the clipboard the paste event is not even firing:

```
window.addEventListener("paste",function () {
   alert('paste');
   debugger;
   var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
   alert(JSON.stringify(items)); // will give you the mime types

   for (index in items) {
       var item = items[index];
       if (item.kind === 'file') {

           var blob = item.getAsFile();
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = function (event) {
               alert(event.target.result)

           }; // data url!
           reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
       }
   }
});
```

I suspect security issues, but I can't find any definite answer, or whether there's different way to do this that works for Internet Explorer.

Specifically I'm using Ace Editor in a Web Browser control and there is a text selection active in the editor and I'd like to be able to capture the image pasted. I've also tried this in standalone IE 11 both from a file and loaded through a Web server (just to see if the security zone is the culprit) but it doesn't seem to make a difference where it's run from - past just doesn't fire.

**Added note**
Also noticed that on GitHub you can paste images from clipboard into textboxes and it uploads and shows them. That also doesn't work with IE 11...

Comment: The Microsoft Edge team is [looking into this issue](https://twitter.com/SampsonMSFT/status/750810948097568768).